# What are the possible causes of a faculty position not being filled?

Tags: job-search, tenure-track

I applied for a tenure-track faculty position at a particular institution in the U.S. I was selected for a skype interview, but was not invited for an on-campus visit. I snooped around on the department seminar web page, but did not find any evidence that this particular department actually ever invited anybody for an on-campus interview.

Today, I received an email from the department stating:

> Thank you for your interest in the faculty position within the Electrical and Computer Engineering Department at the University of [redacted]. Our search to fill this position produced many impressive applicants. **However, for a number of reasons beyond the department’s control, the position was not filled.**

I can think of a couple of reasons that a department may not fill a vacancy, such as:

- the finalists all ended up taking a job somewhere else
- none of the finalists could agree to the terms offered by the department

So, besides those possibilities listed above, what are the other possible causes of a faculty position going unfilled?

Comment: Possible reasons: they no longer have the funding; none of the applicants matched their criteria.

Comment: Most common reason: **Everyone offered the position said no.**

Comment: @JeffE it doesn't sound like OP said no.

Comment: At a university here I know a spot once was not filled for gender-equality reasons! The university said they have to hire a woman, but there was just no competent women that applied for that position!

Comment: @Jigg: OP wasn't offered the position.

Comment: At least at the institutions I know that would bother with Skype interviews in the field of math (i.e. not schools that essentially only hire by invitation), if the first round of on-campus candidates declined, they would just move down the list until someone accepted the invitation of an on-campus interview. With hundreds of applications for each position, it would be unlikely that they could find nobody willing to do that. Of course, things could be different in the field the OP applied in.

Comment: I'm addressing the actual stated question — **Why might a position go unfilled?** — and deliberately ignoring the (plausible but uncertain) hypothesis that nobody was even interviewed. Some departments are _very_ good at not advertising their interview talks.

Comment: Not that it matters, but the seminar web page for this particular department listed those job talks given for the previous job posting cycle.

Comment: @OswaldVeblen Some schools go down the list only few spots. I heard of a position where 5 people were called for an interview, they moved down the list to #3, and after they declined they decided it might be better to reopen it at a later time.

Comment: I knew of one relatively small department with 2 long-term unfilled positions.  It turned out that the three tenured faculty had significantly divergent opinions on hiring and were essentially waiting for someone to die.  That deadlock ended in an attempted murder and successful suicide.  One of their postdocs...wasn't surprised.  Politics in top-ten universities can be surprisingly inefficient.  To be fair, hiring everywhere tends to have 'quirks'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will probably never know the full reason, because departments are not quick to air their internal issues with job candidates. But here are a few possible reasons:

- The search was halted by higher administration. One possible reason to do this so late in the process is because of funding changes (e.g. the funding for the position disappeared or was reallocated elsewhere).
- The search was halted by the HR department due to some violation of hiring practices.
- The search committee was unable to come to an agreement about who to bring to campus for an interview, or the dean rejected all the candidates before they were interviewed.
- Although this is less likely, someone who had planned to retire might have decided not to retire, or someone from another department may have been moved into the department (e.g. for legal reasons to settle a complaint).

Comment: One more reason (perhaps related to #1 on your list): A totally unrelated search in another department brought in a senior candidate with a trailing spouse. The hiring of that spouse meant that a slot was lost in the grand shuffle.

Comment: There were lots of instances of #1 in the 2008-2009 hiring season.  When the [financial crisis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_crisis_of_2007%E2%80%9308#Impact_on_financial_markets) started getting dire in fall 2008, endowments and state budgets dropped, and many schools instituted hiring freezes and canceled searches.

Answer (score 1):

There may have been a change of administration in the middle of a search, and the new administrator didn't like the position description posted.